# Op-amp not increasing amplitude of signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, sine, low-voltage

I was doing some LTSpice simulation with an op-amp to amplify a 1 millivolt 40 kHz sine wave. However, in the output signal, it had just raised the voltage of the whole waveform, it decreased the amplitude. The amplitude now was under 500 microvolts. I was expecting it to only increase the amplitude of the signal.

[image: schematic]

[image: waveform]

Comment: You appear to be injecting an AC (both positive and negative) signal into a non-inverting input. What's your thinking about what should happen when the input signal goes negative?

Comment: The LT1001 is nowhere near capable of working rail to rail. And according to the datasheet "The LT1001 is specified over a wide range of power supply
voltages from ±3V to ±18V"

Comment: kudos to LT for properly modeling the opamp wrt supply voltage ;)

Comment: @Finbarr It works with lower voltages too if you have enough gain like in this circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since you are giving it a 0V and 3.3V supply, an input of signal around 0V or even negative are invalid.

It would need a negative supply to handle signals near 0V.

Comment: How do I give it a negative supply? Should I feed 5V into an inverting amplifier and use the output?

Comment: @epicMan123 Change the negative supply pin, which you have now connected to 0V ground, to a supply that gives the opamp a negative voltage. Just like you have a supply for positive voltage already. Try giving it more voltage like +/- 10V.

Comment: I changed the power supply to 10V but the problem still persists. The amplitude is still millivolt level.

Comment: @epicMan123 It sounds like you only changed the 3.3V to 10V. I don't know if you gave it a negative supply. I can't see what errors you have.

Comment: Took a bit of thinking but I got it now. I made a new 5V voltage supply and labeled the + as ground and wired the - to the op-amp's negative supply. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another problem.. when I increase the values of the resistors, the amplification stops when the amplitude is about 18mV. After that when I increase the resistances nothing happens. What could be causing that? I need the gain to be about 100, but now it stops at around 18.

Comment: @epicMan123 The op-amp has gain-bandwidth product typically 800 kHz, but can be as low as 400 kHz. You have 40 kHz signal and so you can have gain of 10 but op-amp might not even be capable of 20, and certainly can't achieve 100.